# If kotlin package has multiple main function, how can I call specific one?

Tags: kotlin

I want to test the main function for competitive programming.

Kotlin can have multiple main functions, however how to call specific one?
In other words, how to specify a function in the specific file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on compilation and execution tools:

- When you call "java -jar my-app.jar", JVM looks into the [manifest file to find main class name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).
- If you compile application with Gradle, [you can define mainClassName](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) as part of application plugin (which created executable jar).
- Maven tool has [property for the main class too](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make).
- IntelliJ Idea has independent settings, so you can specify multiple build configuration with different parameters. And you can put [entry point there](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-configuration-options.html).

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, In JVM, in tests, we can create Java class which delegates calls to target `main` functions.

This is based on the fact that by default `FileName.kt` translates into Java class `FileNameKt`

```java
public final class Mains {

    public static void section01() {
        Section01Kt.main();
    }

    public static void section02() {
        Section02Kt.main();
    }
}
```

Then use wrapper method in tests:

```kotlin
    @Test 
    fun testMain() {
        Mains.section01() // instead of main()
    }
```